# Payment Gateways Options and Related Questions

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, shopping-cart, silverstripe

We've built our Ecommerce site in Silverstripe, and now we need to implement a payment gateways. I'm just wondering what are the options are there for us? In another word what are the good gateways to use?

Also I did this tutorial about Ecommerce, the tutor said Paypal is a payment processor rather than payment gateways, is this true? As my understanding to use gateways is better than processor. Anyone can give me a bit more detailed info on this? Any suggestions and advice for choosing gateways for Ecommerce would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It dependes upon what is your location.there are number of service providers in this field few of them are

1. Authorizenet.com
2. LinkPoint
3. Verisign also has a payment gateway